# React Native Android Button Shadow

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to achieve a button (touchable opacity) shadow on android using react native.

I see [documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.34/docs/view.html#style) which suggests the `elevation` attribute can be used, but various attempts to use this attribute do not produce the desired effect...

```
<TouchableOpacity>
  <View elevation={3}>
    <Text>Hello World</Text>
  </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

...

```
<TouchableOpacity>
  <View style={{elevation:3}}>
    <Text>Hello World</Text>
  </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The `elevation` property is available from Android 5.0 (also known as Lollipop) so check the version of the device or emulator you're using.
Also, try to set a `backgroundColor` to the view you're trying to add a shadow to.